# How can I get index of the value inside forEach loop?

Tags: javascript

Absolutely NewBee

How Can I find out the index of the value and not the value itself inside forEach loop Currently I have following code which just gives my the value of `userAnswers` :

```
    correctAnswers: [], // [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4, 3]
    userAnswers: [],    // [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4, 3]

    let tempArr = [];
    const findingTotal = userAnswers.forEach(
        (value, index) =>
            value === correctAnswers[index]
                ? (Total += 1)
                : tempArr.push(value)
    );
```

In the above example I want to get index which is `2` and not the value (1) itself ?

Comment: Do you mean `push(index)`?

Comment: I mean the index of the `userAnswers` array ?

Comment: is very cool to use forEach, but sometimes (and specially for a newbie) is clear and easy to understand a classic "for" sentence. :)

Comment: Actually thats very true I was just following an online article and thats what was suggested there :)

Comment: `forEach` doesn't return anything, so the actual intent of the code confuses me a bit. Maybe you wanted to do `let findingTotal = 0` then add to it inside the loop body? Not related to the question, I'm just curious

Answer (score 1):

```
correctAnswers: [], // [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4, 3]
userAnswers: [],    // [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4, 3]

let tempArr = [];
let Total = 0; 
userAnswers.forEach(
    (value, index) =>
        value === correctAnswers[index]
            ? (Total += 1)
            : tempArr.push(index)
);
```

**tempArr.push(index)**, findingTotal is not used too

Comment: Can't believe it I did that mistake !! Thanks anyways :)